# How to fill large 2d area (object with size 4000x4000) by repeating small sprite (200px x 200px) in Unity3D without use <Image>?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have large resizable object with dimensions about 4000x4000 and picture, which can be used as an element of the "mosaic" which creates background.

I think that I should use SpriteRenderer, but I have no idea how to do it correctly:

```
public Vector2 Dimensions {
    set {
        Texture2D texture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(IMAGE_PATH);            
        Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, value.x, value.y), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 1);
        BackgroundSprite = sp;
    }
}
```

After this block of code I get:
ArgumentException: Could not create sprite (0.000000, 0.000000, 5400.000000, 3000.000000) from a 200x100 texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a RenderTexture, draw your texture with http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawTexture.html on it, save the resulting texture.